# BASH: ls first 5 from $PATH without displaying errors

Tags: bash

I'm starting with bash at university, anyone has any idea how to solve that problem:

Show first 5 files for each directory from $PATH variable, if some directory doesn't exist, don't show error message.

Solution can be something like:

``` ls -a ``echo $PATH | sed "s/:/ /g"`` 2> /dev/null ```

it works, maybe there exists other option but I don't know how to limit results by 5 per each show block?

Comment: The first five by name? Size? Raw directory position? mtime? I assume you want dotfiles (`ls -a`) but do you want '.' and '..'?

Comment: Nothing said about that, so it could be by default by name, the idea is to list results limited by 5 results only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code :

```
printf '%s\n' ${PATH//:/ } |
    while read dir; do
        /bin/ls 2>/dev/null -1 "$dir" |
            head -5
    done
```

- the `${PATH//:/* /}` part use [*bash parameter expansion*](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe)
- `printf '%s\n'` is printing any words separated by spaces on newlines
- `/bin/ls -1` list files on newlines. I puts the full PATH to override the alias
- `head -5` print the first 5 lines

**edit**

This is another solution using `perl` with a formatted output :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -lw

use strict;
use Env qw/PATH/;

my $hash = {};
my @paths = split ":", $PATH;

push @{ $hash->{"$_"} }, glob "${_}/*" for @paths;

foreach my $key (keys(%$hash)) {
    next unless $hash->{$key}->[0];
    print "$key";
    for (my $i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
        my $line = $hash->{$key}->[$i];
        print "  $line" if $line;
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

Output example :

```
/opt/kde/bin
  /opt/kde/bin/checkXML
  /opt/kde/bin/cupsdconf
  /opt/kde/bin/cupsdoprint
  /opt/kde/bin/dcop
  /opt/kde/bin/dcopclient


/usr/bin
  /usr/bin/2to3
  /usr/bin/2to3-2.7
  /usr/bin/2to3-3.2
  /usr/bin/7z
  /usr/bin/7za
```

Answer (score 1):

Not helping you too much by not explaining ([man bash](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)...)

```
(IFS=:; for a in $PATH; do find "$a" -type f | head -n 5; done) 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: No need `;` after `IFS` & no need `( )` : that produce a subshell. So : `{ IFS=: for a in $PATH; do find "$a" -type f | head -n 5; done; } 2> /dev/null`

Comment: @sputnick `syntax error near unexpected token 'do'`. Also, why are you saying this? This is not a golf

Comment: Because of the `{}`, `;` is needed finally. I said that, because using a subshell in this case cause a not needed overhead.

Comment: @sputnick I get the error when using you variant. Did you _try it_? (By the way, why would you use `{}` if a subshell isn't necessary, after all?)

Answer (score 0):

This should work, have a look:

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=':' read -a array <<<"$PATH"

for i in "${array[@]}"; do
ls -al $i 2>/dev/null | head -5
done
```

command IFS=..... splits $PATH variable into array, then looping array showing results limited by 5 first values